# If a substance enhanced the ability to stay mindful, and didnt cause intoxication or carelessness, would it still violate the fifth precept?

Tags: five-precepts, mindfulness

this subject is so controversial i cant get a solid explanation.
i am retrying an attempt to find better advice on the subject of continuing unorthodox methods that are controversial if they are truly of benefit to the individuals practice. (even if they may commonly be detrimental to others.)

Comment: 'truly of benefit to the individuals practice'? could you explain this point?

Comment: as in... it helps... with practice.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the fifth precept specifically refers to substances that cause "intoxication and carelessness", such a hypothetical substance would of course not violate it, no.

Comment: I didnt think so. Thanks Bhante. I e been getting a lot of benifit from Monk Radio and all your videos, so thanks for that also... :0)

Answer (score 2):

Food substances like Water, Carbohydrates, Fats, Sugar, Protein, Minerals, Vitamins etc. don't violate the 5th precept. They actually nourish the body, if taken in appropriate quantities. That is helpful for the development of the mind as well. Is there anything specific you are referring to?

Comment: oh i commented down there... new to the site.

Comment: Sati is not recollection. Sati is awareness. Buddhism promotes the right awareness. One can exercise the mind to increase memory capacity. While using a supplement for it does not break the 5th precept, it can cause an addiction. An addiction can be a hindrance to the progress in the path.

Comment: Recollection of being attentive to the four foundations of satipatthana might help give a better understanding of my meaning (or view of sati).

Answer (score 2):

Such a substance already does exist, it is called *Camellia sinensis* also known as ... regular tea! This traditional drink of Zen-Buddhist monks stimulates the mind and enhances one's ability to stay mindful, without causing intoxication or carelessness.

> The biographical tradition is littered with apocryphal tales about
>   Bodhidharma's life and circumstances. In one version of the story, he
>   is said to have fallen asleep seven years into his nine years of
>   wall-gazing. Becoming angry with himself, he cut off his eyelids to
>   prevent it from happening again. According to the legend, as his
>   eyelids hit the floor the first tea plants sprang up; and thereafter
>   tea would provide a stimulant to help keep students of Chán awake
>   during meditation. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhidharma))

Comment: Sankha... what im specifically talking about is irrelevant. But the question clears up the use of all kinds of herbal supplements in oriental holistic practices. Take ginko for example... no intoxication, increases bloodtlow to the brain which is said to enhance mental capacity and aid in memory... Sati = Recollection... a faculty of memory.